# Make Notepad++ collapse Python triple double content?

Tags: python, notepad++

*Q:* I've tried all Notepad++ Preferences and Options and Style Configurator but I couldn't find a way to collapse Python docstring (the content between triple double quotes). Can we do that or is there any plug-in to support that need?

*Context:* I decided to move to Notepad++ from ipython notebook (which is an interactive shell running inside a browser window). The simple reasons that Notepad++ offers far more flexible in customizing editing environment, and it has better syntax highlighting.

Now I miss the function of collapsing a chunk of docstring within the code to have a better sense of the code structure (normally they're OpenCV2 docs, I just want to make them available in the script, without going to the online document every time I need references).

**E.g.** Netbeans allows collapse chunk of code, or comment blocks or Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ will allow you to collapse whatever it thinks are blocks of codes, which it decides based on indents.  So the simple answer is to indent your doc strings

```
"""
    This is a collapsible doc string
"""


"""This is not"""

"""
Neither is this
"""

"""
 This one is, but I think it looks a little odd"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only solves for doc strings and in cases where people are willing to adjust the message in the triple quoted text.  I currently have test cases where I have to paste in a complete message and I use triple double quotes.  In this case, I am not going to adjust my multiline test message and sadly, notepad++ will only fold the first paragraph.

```
    testcases.append("""Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
a type specimen book.

It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
popularized...""")
```